# Why did the static stop working on the server?

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

Static files stopped working when the project was deployed

I have tried various configurations of settings, nginx and docker-compose.

When inserting a direct link from the Internet to bootstrap files into the base template, the static started working, it did not stop in the admin panel

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream coolsite_web {
    server coolsite_web:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name zatolokina-clinic.ru www.zatolokina-clinic.ru;
    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://coolsite_web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /coolsite/static;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /coolsite/media;
   }
}
```

**docker-compose**

```
coolsite_web:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: zatolokina
  expose:
    - "8080"
  volumes:
    - ./coolsite:/coolsite
    - static_volume:/coolsite/static
    - media_volume:/coolsite/media
  env_file:
    - .env
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_HOST=pg_db
    - POSTGRES_DB:${POSTGRES_DB}
    - POSTGRES_USER:${POSTGRES_USER}
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  command: >
    sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear &&
           python manage.py makemigrations &&
           python manage.py migrate &&
           gunicorn coolsite.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080"
  depends_on:
    - pg_db

nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - static_volume:/coolsite/static
    - media_volume:/coolsite/media
    - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  restart:
    always
  depends_on:
    - coolsite_web
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UePj.png)

I also entered the **ls -l /coolsite/static** command and got total 12

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec 13 15:25 admin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 13 15:25 debug_toolbar
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec 13 15:25 django_extensions

Comment: What is BASE_DIR in settings.py?

Comment: You're mounting a named volume `static_volume` over both the Nginx content and the source code in the image; whatever's in that volume will replace the content in both places.  How does data get into that named volume, and how do you update its content?

Comment: @JohnGordon BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: @David Maze
 For the most part, the data gets there exclusively during development. They are not updated after the deployment

Comment: In alias trailing slash must match with location `alias /coolsite/static/;` If still does not work after fixing please post nginx error.log messages related to static files urls.

Comment: @IvanStarostin 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2023:18:05:22 +0000] "GET /images/favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://zatolokina-clinic.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.5993.771 YaBrowser/23.11.2.771 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: Please update your question with log details, don't post to comments. `/images/` does not match any of two locations.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name zatolokina-clinic.ru www.zatolokina-clinic.ru;
    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /coolsite/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /coolsite/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://coolsite_web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

This worked for my website:

```
upstream pingli_api {
   server 127.0.0.1:9817;
}

server {
    server_name zwp.xxx.top;
    client_max_body_size 30m;

    location /media {
      alias /home/wenping/coding/pingli/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/wenping/coding/pingli/static;
    }

    location /docs {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://pingli_api;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://pingli_api;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://pingli_api;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/zwp.xxx.top/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/zwp.xxx.top/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the result has not changed
"GET /static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404